# Find common values from 2 list of tuples and add the values from one tuple to another

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

I have 2 lists with tuples as their elements. One element of tuple is to be matched to the tuple from other list and corresponfing values are to be added from one tuple to another.

My 2 lists are :

```
l1 = [('Receipt total', 10),('Total Amount (AED)', 10),('Grand total', 10),('Net Amount', 9),
 ('Total Amount', 9),('Total (words are in between)', 6)]

l2 = [('Total Amount', ['593.52']), ('Total (words are in between)', ['593.52'])]
```

The keys `Total Amount` and `Total (words are in between)` in l2 are to be matched from l1 and the value corresponding to keys present in l1 `9` and `6` respectively in this case are to be added to either l2 or a new list.

Expected output:

```
l2 = [('Total Amount', ['593.52'],[9]), ('Total (words are in between)', ['593.52'],[6])]
```

I'll be happy to provide further clarification and I am unable to think about this would happen and I am sorry if this seems too messy and I looked for similar questions but nothing seemed apt
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For readability I would create a temporarily dictionary of the `l1` to easier do the look-up on the keys.

Unpack the tuples in `l2` and compare the keys with those in the `l1`-dictionary. Create a new tuple if match and wrap everything in a list

```
l1_map = {k: v for k, v in l1}
l2_updated = [(key, num, [l1_map[key]]) for key, num in l2 if key in l1_map]
```

Result:

```
[('Total Amount', ['593.52'], [9]),
 ('Total (words are in between)', ['593.52'], [6])]
```

Comment: I do think this answer is easier to read. upvoted

Answer (score 1):

First create a dict from l1 and then alter l2:

```
D1=dict(l1)
l2=[t + ([D1[t[0]]],) for t in l2]
```

output:

```
[('Total Amount', ['593.52'], [9]), ('Total (words are in between)', ['593.52'], [6])]
```